# Escape sequences unprocessed under the "cygwin" terminal

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, ansi-escape

I have a Java application which uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to display colours, position the cursor, etc.

It works fine under regular Unices,
and also under `xterm` and `mintty`(in *Cygwin*),
but I'm having trouble running it under the `cygwin` terminal (i. e. `bash` launched from `cmd.exe`).

As you can see from the screen shot:

[image]

escape sequences are output "as is", without processing. On the other hand, I can easily run smth like `echo -e '\033[1;31mTest'` -- and colour text will be just there.

At the same time, if I launch exactly the same application from a [*Midnight Commander*](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) subshell, escape sequences produced by the application will be interpreted correctly:

[image]

Also, if I log in to my Windows box using SSH (i. e. replace the local connection with the remote one, but retain the same `cygwin` terminal), again, escape sequences are processed just fine.

It looks like when a subshell of some kind is created (`mc` or `ssh`), the terminal is put into some other mode. But playing with `stty` wasn't helpful, nor was export'ing `TERM=ansi`.

Could anyone please suggest any solution?

I'm running

```
CYGWIN_NT-6.3 UNIT-725 2.5.1(0.297/5/3) 2016-04-21 22:14 x86_64 Cygwin
```

and Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if you launch Cygwin's bash from cmd.exe, it will continue to use the console window provided by Windows rather than creating its own.  The console in the latest build of Windows 10 supports ANSI escape sequences (though I believe it has to be explicitly turned on) but previous versions don't.  I don't know whether there is any way to make this work.  Your best option is probably to provide a launcher that starts your application in the correct way.

Comment: ... although the fact that `echo` works suggests that Cygwin has some sort of translation layer.  If you fed the output through Cygwin somehow, that might work.  Maybe a bash script that redirects the output from your process and echoes it to the console?  Or a Cygwin-based Java interpreter, if there is any such thing.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the point is, `bash.exe` already has said translation layer (escape sequences -> Win32 API console calls) when running as a direct child of `cmd.exe`. The question is why the above translation sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: The output isn't going through `bash.exe` though, it is going directly from Java to the console.  The reason `echo` works is that it is a Cygwin application, with its own translation layer, it has nothing to do with whether you run it from bash or not.  (Even when running natively on Linux, bash doesn't intercept output from its children; why would it?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for an application to be able to use ANSI escape sequences when launched from `cmd.exe` (`TERM=cygwin`), either the application *itself* needs to be linked with `cygwin1.dll`, or its output needs to be filtered through *another one* which is (e. g.: `mc` or `ssh` subshells).

The same *C* program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char esc = 0x1b;
    printf("%c[31;91;1mHello, World!%c[0m\n", esc, esc);
    return 0;
}
```

supports colour output when compiled with *Cygwin GCC*:

```
$ ldd test-ansi-escape.exe
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffeeb450000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffee92c0000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffee8700000)
    cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x180040000)
```

but displays garbage like

```
←[31;91;1mHello, World!←[0m
```

when compiled with *MSVC* or `mingw64-x86_64-gcc`:

```
$ ldd test-ansi-escape.exe
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffeeb450000)
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x770a0000)
    wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x76fd0000)
    wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/wow64win.dll (0x77020000)
    wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/wow64cpu.dll (0x77090000)
    ??? => ??? (0x1040000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x76480000)
    ??? => ??? (0x1040000)
    ??? => ??? (0x1040000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x76480000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x74b40000)
    MSVCR120D.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/MSVCR120D.dll (0x62b90000)
```

An alternative solution is using [*ConEmu*](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) as the external output filter (`bash.exe` running as a direct child of `ConEmu.exe`). This approach doesn't require linking with `cygwin1.dll`, as output filtering is performed by *ConEmu* itself. The downside is that *ConEmu*'s support for escape sequences is limited (particularly, it doesn't understand the *VT100 alternate character set* used for line drawing).